# Is there an equivalent for map or fmap to replace while loops?

Tags: functional-programming

Haskell replaces for loops over iteratable objects with `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` or
`fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. (This question isn't limited to Haskell, I'm just using the syntax here.)

Is there something similar that replaces a *while* loop, like

`wmap :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> ([b] -> Bool) -> [b]`?

This function returns a list of `b`.

The first argument is a function that takes a list and computes a value that will end up in the list returned by `wmap` (so it's a very specific kind of while loop).

The second argument is the list that we use as our starting point.

The third argument is a function that evaluates the stoping criteria.

And as a functor,

`wfmap :: (f a -> b) -> f a -> (f b -> Bool) -> f b`

For example, a [Jacobi solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) would look like this (with `b` now the same type as `a`):

`jacobi :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> ([a] -> Bool) -> [a]`

What I'm looking for isn't really pure. `wmap` could have values that mutate internally, but only exist inside the function. It also has nondeterministic runtime, if it terminates at all.

In the case of a [Gauss-Seidel solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method), there would be no return value, since the `[a]` would be modified in place.

Something like this:

`gs :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> ([a] -> Bool) -> ???`

1. Does `wmap` or `wfmap` exist as part of any language by default, and what is it called?

**Answer 1** (thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)): Instead of the silly `wmap`/`wfmap` signature, we already have [`until`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:until).

2. Does an in place version of `until` exist for things like `gs`?

Comment: The generic "for loop over an iterable" is not `fmap` but [a `fold`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold). The list-producing while loop you are looking for is [`unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr). A generic repeated computation with a stop predicate is [`until`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:until) (but you can write a similar `while` of course).

Comment: At least for me, instead of reading those signatures, I would have a much easier time to see what he is looking for if he gave some imperative while loop function we could "translate" for him. Also, there is functional (as e.g. F#, Ocaml, ... ) and FUNCTIONAL (as in Haskell et. al). 2 Major differences: The former allow mutation of arrays, while the latter does not (okay IO monad and stuff... but it looks ugly then). Also, Haskell is lazy. So composition works much more efficiently than what one might think. `takeWhile pred . fmap mapping $ input` is still a lazy expression!

Comment: @BitTickler, there are pseudocode examples of what I'm trying to do [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Algorithm) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Algorithm), which are also in my question. That pseudocode contains an impertive while loop function you can "translate" into FP. Yes, I am expecting a monad of some sort where I've written `???` in my question since the syntax I chose to express this idea is in Haskell :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a proverb in engineering which states "Don't generalize before you have at least 3 implementations". There is some truth to it - especially when looking for new functional iteration concepts *before* doing it by foot a few times.

"Doing it by foot" here means, you should - if there is no friendly helper function you know of - resort to recursion. Write your "special cases" recursively. Preferably in a tail recursive form. Then, if you start to see recurring patterns, you might come up with a way to refactor into some recurring iteration scheme and its "kernel".

Let's for the sake of clarification of the above, assume you never heard of `foldl` and you want accumulate a result from iteration over a list... Then, you would write something like:

```hs
myAvg values =
    total / (length values)
    where
        mySum acc [] = acc
        mySum acc (x:xs) = mySum (acc + x) xs
        total = mySum 0 values
```

And after doing this a couple of times, the pattern might show, that the recursions in those where clauses always look darn similar. You might then come up with a name like "fold" or "reduce" for that inner recursion snippet and end up with:

```hs
myAvg values = (foldl (+) 0.0 values) / fromIntegral (length values) :: Float
```

So, if you are looking for helper functions which help with your use-cases, my advice is you first write a few instances as recursive functions and then look for patterns.

So, with all that said, let's get our fingers wet and see how the Jacobi algorithm *could* translate to Haskell. Just so we have something to talk about. Now - usually I do not use Haskell for anything requiring arrays (containers with O(1) element access), because there are at least 5 array packages I know of and I would have to read for 2 days to decide which one is suitable for my application. TL;DR;). So I stick with lists and NO package dependencies beyond prelude in the code below. But that is - given the size of the example equations we try to solve is tiny - not a bad thing at all. Plus, the code demonstrates, that list comprehensions in **lazy** Haskell allow for un-imperative and yet performant operations on sets of cells (e.g. in the matrix), without any need for explicit looping.

```hs
type Matrix = [[Double]]

-- sorry - my mind went blank while looking for a better name for this...
-- but it is useful nonetheless 
idefix nr nc =
  [ [(r,c) | c <- [0..nc-1]] | r <- [0..nr-1]]

matElem m (r,c) = (m !! r) !! c

transpose (r,c) = (c,r)

matrixDim m = (length m, length . head $ m)

-- constructs a Matrix by enumerating the indices and querying
-- 'unfolder' for a value.
-- try "unfoldMatrix 3 3 id" and you see how indices relate to
-- cells in the matrix.
unfoldMatrix nr nc unfolder =
  fmap (\row -> fmap (\cell -> unfolder cell) row) $ idefix nr nc

-- Not really needed for Jacobi problem but good
-- training to get our fingers wet with unfoldMatrix.
transposeMatrix m =
  let (nr,nc) = matrixDim m in
      unfoldMatrix nc nr (matElem m . transpose)
      
addMatrix m1 m2
  | (matrixDim m1) == (matrixDim m2) =
    let (nr,nc) = matrixDim m1 in
      unfoldMatrix nr nc (\idx -> matElem m1 idx + matElem m2 idx)

subMatrix m1 m2
  | (matrixDim m1) == (matrixDim m2) =
    let (nr,nc) = matrixDim m1 in
      unfoldMatrix nr nc (\idx -> matElem m1 idx - matElem m2 idx)
      
dluMatrix :: Matrix -> (Matrix,Matrix,Matrix)
dluMatrix m
  | (fst . matrixDim $ m) == (snd . matrixDim $ m) =
    let n = fst . matrixDim $ m in
      (unfoldMatrix n n (\(r,c) -> if r == c then matElem m (r,c) else 0.0)
      ,unfoldMatrix n n (\(r,c) -> if r > c then matElem m (r,c) else 0.0)
      ,unfoldMatrix n n (\(r,c) -> if c > r then matElem m (r,c) else 0.0)
      )
      
mulMatrix m1 m2
  | (snd . matrixDim $ m1) == (fst . matrixDim $ m2) =
    let (nr, nc) = ((fst . matrixDim $ m1),(snd . matrixDim $ m2)) in
      unfoldMatrix nr nc
          (\(ro,co) ->
             sum [ matElem m1 (ro,i) * matElem m2 (i,co) | i <- [0..nr-1]]
          )

isSquareMatrix m = let (nr,nc) = matrixDim m in nr == nc

jacobi :: Double -> Matrix -> Matrix -> Matrix -> Matrix
jacobi errMax a b x0
  | isSquareMatrix a && (snd . matrixDim $ a) == (fst . matrixDim $ b) =
      approximate x0
     -- We could possibly avoid our hand rolled recursion
     -- with the help of 'loop' from Control.Monad.Extra
     -- according to hoogle. But it would  not look better at all.
     -- loop (\x -> let x' = jacobiStep x in if converged x' then Right x' else Left x') x0
  where
    (nra, nca) = matrixDim a
    (d,l,u) = dluMatrix a
    dinv = unfoldMatrix nra nca (\(r,c) ->
                                   if r == c
                                   then 1.0 / matElem d (r,c)
                                   else 0.0)
    lu = addMatrix l u
    converged x =
      let delta = (subMatrix (mulMatrix a x) b) in
        let (nrd,ncd) = matrixDim delta in
          let err = sum (fmap (\idx -> let v = matElem delta idx in v * v)
                         (concat (idefix nrd ncd))) in
            err < errMax
    jacobiStep x =
      (mulMatrix dinv (subMatrix b (mulMatrix lu x)))
    approximate x =
      let x' = jacobiStep x in
        if converged x' then x' else approximate x'
    
    
wikiExample errMax =
  let a = [[ 2.0, 1.0],[5.0,7.0]] in
    let b = [[11], [13]] in
      jacobi errMax a b [[1.0],[1.0]]
```

Function `idefix`, despite it's silly name, IMHO is an eye opener for people coming from non-lazy languages. Their first reflex is to get scared: "What - he creates a list with the indices instead of writing loops? What a waste!" But a waste, it is not in lazy languages. What you see in this function (the list comprehension) produces a *lazy* list. It is not really created. What happens behind the scene is similar in spirit to what LINQ does in C# - `IEnumerator<T>` juggling.

We use `idefix` a second time when we want to sum all elements in our `delta`. There, we do not care about the concrete structure of the matrix. And so we use the standard prelude function `concat` to flatten the Matrix into a linear list. Lazy as well, of course. That is the beauty.

The next notable difference to the imperative wikipedia pseudo code is, that using matrix notation is much less complicated compared to nested looping and operating on single cells. Fortunately, the wikipedia article shows both. So, instead of a while loop with 2 nested loops, we only need an equivalent of the outermost while loop. Which is covered by our 2 liner recursive function `approximate`.

Lessons learned:

- Lists and list comprehensions can help simplify code otherwise requiring nested loops. (In lazy languages).
- Ocaml and Common Lisp have mutability and built in arrays and loops. That makes a package, very convenient when translating algorithms from imperative languages or imperative pseudo code.
- Haskell has immutability and no built in arrays and no loops, but instead it has a similarly powerful set of tools, namely Laziness, tail call optimization and a terse syntax. That combination requires more planning (and writing some usually short helper functions) instead of the classical C approach of "Let's write it all in main()."
- Sometimes it is easier to write a 2 line long recursive function than to think about how to abstract it.

Comment: “because there are at least 5 array packages I know of and I would have to read for 2 days to decide” – yeah, I see what you mean. Though in practice, before you revert to lists you can always default to [vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector), which is the go-to for single-dimensional, non-parallelised arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In FP, you don't usually try to fit everything "inside the loop." You do one step and pass it on to the next function. There are lots of combinations that are useful in different situations. A common replacement for a while loop is a `map` followed by a `takeWhile` or a `dropWhile`, but there are many other possibilities, up to just plain recursion.

Comment: `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` seem to return a list that can be smaller than the original list. The Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel solvers require the returned (or mutated) list to be the same size. I’m wondering if there’s a way to abstract the while loop completely. For example, with the Gauss-Seidel function, I expect a monad (`???` in my question) that wraps `()` to be the return type. Unwrapping the monad runs the Gauss-Seidel solver — no while loop for the user to implement — and once that completes, the program can continue to the next line in a `do` block.

Comment: @masterBuilderBenny Usually you'd just write a recursive monadic function to do that, but [sure there is](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html).

Comment: `iterateUntilM` _might_ be what I'm looking for... I'll have to look at it a little further.